# strings seemingly not equivalent using substring()

Tags: java, substring, equivalence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

i am new to java so don't expect things to be easy but this has me totally shell shocked.
why on earth doesn't the if statement evaluate properly:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class StringMystery extends JFrame {

    JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
    String string1 = "abcde";
    String string2 = string1.substring(0,4);

    public StringMystery() {

        setLayout(null);

        txt.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 100);
        add(txt);

        txt.setText(string2);

        //string 2 is definitely equal to "abcd" but this doesn't evaluate:
        if (string2 == "abcd"){     
            txt.setText("string2 = abcd");          
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringMystery jtxt = new StringMystery();
        jtxt.setSize(200,200);
        jtxt.setTitle("String Mystery");

        jtxt.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of the other million string == questions

Answer (score 8):

Do not (**ever**) use `==` for comparison unless you want to compare the actual references. You need to use the `.equals()` method. And for `String` you may consider writing `"abcd".equals(myStr)` - because myStr can potentially be `null`.

Note that in Java strings are [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) and `==` might sometimes give correct results, but by no means you should rely on that.

Comment: amazingly quick response. thanks.
are all oop s languages like this? why can't they just make it work with ==

Comment: @Gimli: No.  C# and C++ support operator overloading, and Javascript treats strings specially.

Answer (score 6):

`==` compares objects by reference, not by value.

You have two different string objects that contain the same value, so `==` returns false.

You need to call `.equals()`.

Comment: for newbies like me who find this thread the syntax is
string2.equals("abcd")